# Removing duplicate field from object using Typescript/JavaScript in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have following object of zip codes. I am trying to get only the unique values of zip code so repeated values are removed.

```
this.listuser = [{"zip": 12345},{"zip": 78601},{ "zip": 12345},{ "zip": 78601}];
```

I am trying to remove duplicate values of zip and

```
this.resl=this.listuser.filter(zip, i,a)=> i===a.indedOf(zip));
```

Basically this does nothing. There is no error and still I see the duplicates. 
I have tried other solutions from Stack Overflow for some reason same thing no error but still duplicate show up.

Please let me know how to fix this so I can get unique values of zip code only.

Comment: What is the purpose of your function inside `filter`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey the solution in that post is from 2010, I can get there to using loops and messy code. I want some modern solution to that.

Comment: Then ask for the that in your question. The second answer uses ES2015 code, BTW. [This answer uses `Set` and does it in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601543/215552) and all of them answer your question. So, it is a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion both worked the 2nd one and the one given here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your condition `(zip, i,a)=> i===a.indexOf(zip)` can't work because is expect to have the same object (means RAM memory address) to work, here you have **different object** with the same value on it.

To play around you have to use two loop to deduplicate your array like following :

```js
var test = [{"zip": 12345},{"zip": 78601},{ "zip": 12345},{ "zip": 78601}];

var dedupe = test.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
  if (! accumulator.find(({zip}) => zip === current.zip)) {
    accumulator.push(current);
  }
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(dedupe);
```

Comment: if you consider my answer not relevant, could you please tell me why ? i will update my answer accordingely

Comment: I didnt do it some one else did I am trying your solution